# iMacros doesn't fill caption and tags on Tumblr image post

Tags: firefox, encoding, imacros

I have a problem using iMacros within tumblr in post image section. I'm using a macbook with OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 and Firefox 40.0.2 and this is my problem:
no caption or tags content is being added when I process my code which is this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_post_photo&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:photo CONTENT=/Users/me/Desktop/blabla.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:xxxx
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:​
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:xxx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLESAVEDROPDOWN:&&CLASS:flat-button<SP>blue<SP>dropdown<SP>options<SP>icon_arrow_carrot_down<SP>pinned-target&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>to<SP>queue
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Queue
```

It just load till it gives me Runtime error.

Thank you very any advise you could give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a part of the code for filling caption and tags:

```
' ...
' wait to load the image
WAIT SECONDS=3
' caption
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>P" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="My image caption"
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
' tag #1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="my tag1"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS=""
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
' tag #2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="my tag2"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS=""
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
' tags etc.
' ...
```