# iMacros doesn't write caption (HTML) and tags in Tumblr post

Tags: html, tumblr, imacros

I'm using Windows 7 and Firefox 44.0.2. I'm trying to schedule some posts on Tumblr using iMacros. When iMacros creates a post it adds an image and I want to write some code in html. Let's say:

```
<div>abcd</div>
```

but neither in caption nor in tags (If I want to write"test") anything appear.

This is my code

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_post_photo&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:photo CONTENT=E:\myDirectory\img.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLEPOSTSETTINGSCOG:&&CLASS:post-settings&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:editorType CONTENT=%html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ace_content&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=WRAP:off&&CLASS:ace_text-input&&SPELLCHECK:false&&ARIA-LABEL:HTML<SP>content&&TXT: CONTENT=<div>abcd</div>
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:​#tags
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:​test
TAG POS=5 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:​test
```

what coould be the problem?

*** UPDATE ***
following the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129194/imacros-doesnt-fill-caption-and-tags-on-tumblr-image-post) by Shugar, I inserted that code and now I can make iMacros write text caption and alt tags but if I make iMacros change into html it won't write code in it. Here:

```
  TAB T=1
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Photo
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:photo CONTENT=E:\myDirectory\img.jpg
    ' here i ask iMacros to change open html instead of plain text caption
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLEPOSTSETTINGSCOG:&&CLASS:post-settings&&TXT:
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:editorType CONTENT=%html
    ' wait to load the image
    WAIT SECONDS=10
    ' caption
    EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>P" BUTTON=0
    EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="<div>abdcdsa</div>"
    WAIT SECONDS=0.5
    ' tag #1
    EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
    EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="my tag1"
    EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS=""
    WAIT SECONDS=0.5
    ' tag #2
    EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
    EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="my tag2"
    EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS=""
    WAIT SECONDS=0.5
    ' tags etc.
    ' ...
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***
after trying the code given by Shugar this is what I have but it stucks on line 11 and keep loading forever:

```
eTAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Photo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:photo CONTENT=C:mydirectory\sample.jpg
' here i ask iMacros to change open html instead of plain text caption
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLEPOSTSETTINGSCOG:&&CLASS:post-settings&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:editorType CONTENT=%html
' wait to load the image
WAIT SECONDS=10
' caption '
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLEPOSTSETTINGSCOG:&&CLASS:post-settings&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:editorType CONTENT=%html
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV" BUTTON=0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=javascript:alert();
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

SET captionHtml "<div>caption text</div>"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>TEXTAREA" CHARS={{captionHtml}}e
```

Comment: Try using experimental recording. "Old school" recording works on some HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: In record options try Experimental recording. http://prntscr.com/a3603q

Comment: This question seems to be solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129194/imacros-doesnt-fill-caption-and-tags-on-tumblr-image-post).

Comment: I checked that answer but it adds only text caption and if I make iMacros select html it doesn't work, I will modify the question including your useful answer on the other question.

Comment: If you want me to receive your comment, mention my user name, as shown in the help note.

Comment: @Shugar Thank you for your answer and sorry for late. I had long business trip and couldn't do anything else. I tried your code but it doesn't work for me. I update my question with your solution in my code. it is in UPDATE 2. Basically it reaches line 11 and it keeps loading forever

Answer (score 0):

Your macro must look like this:

```
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Photo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:photo CONTENT=C:\mydirectory\sample.jpg
' wait to load the image '
WAIT SECONDS=10

' here i ask iMacros to change open html instead of plain text caption '
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-JS-CLICKABLEPOSTSETTINGSCOG:&&CLASS:post-settings&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:editorType CONTENT=%html

' caption '
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV" BUTTON=0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=javascript:alert();
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

SET captionHtml "<div>caption text</div>"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post_buttons>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>TEXTAREA" CHARS={{captionHtml}}
```

At least it works perfectly for me :)